# jQuery keydown event binding - live vs keydown

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, key-bindings, jquery-events

On the Mac in Chrome, Safari, and Opera, both the body live and the document keydown bindings work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append("Focus on this window and press any key");

    $("body").live("keydown", function(event) {
       $("body").append("<p>live on body</p>");            
    });

    $(document).keydown(function() {
       $("body").append("<p>keydown on document</p>");                 
    });
});
```

In Firefox, only the document keydown binding works.

Why does the body live event binding not work in Firefox on the Mac?

*Mac 10.7.1
Chrome 13.0.782.220
Safari 5.1
Opera 11.51
Firefox 6.02*

Example Test: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeGrace/qZVg8/3/

Comment: now that `live` is officially deprecated - are you still interested in an answer? (not saying I _have_ one)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, however binding live on a body seems kind of pointless. Because the live event will bind to the body and then check if the matched tag( in this case body) gets the event(keydown) triggered.

the live function has been made to delegate binds for elements within the body.

In firefox the keydown event doesn't trigger on the body, it triggers on the document.

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function(event) {
   $("body").append("<p>keydown on document</p>");            
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the information but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: the `live` function is now officially deprecated

Comment: @MikeGrace it does. The first event won't trigger because you're binding it to `body` while it fires on the `document`. You're binding the second one to `document`, so it works in both browsers.